# Sending email using "mailgun" with nodejs showing 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailgun

I am working on a NodeJS and ExpressJS project where I need to use Mailgun.

```
app.get('/send', function (req, res) {
    var mailgun = new Mailgun({
        apiKey: api_key,
        domain: domain
    });

    var data = {
        from: frommail,
        to: 'im88@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Hello',
        text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function (err, body) {
        //If there is an error, render the error page
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
            console.log("got an error: ", err);
        } else {

            res.json(data);
            console.log(body);
        }
    });

});
```

While running this code, I am getting an error:

```
{ statusCode :404

}
```

Comment: do you get error code from milgun error. 
or your server returns 404?

Comment: my server returns 404.

Comment: Then mailgun is not a problem. See your routes and method. see your route works or not:  `app.get('/send', function (req, res) {  res.send("Route works");  });`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Btw, I could find out the problem here. The problem was my domain name. I have corrected it. Now, it works fine. The code is working fine.